# .net queue system

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, message-queue

I am building a system which is made up of 2 application

1. ASP.Net Website where jobs will be created for engineers to visit data held in central database
2. Windows Forms Application running on Laptop where jobs will be synced from central database then a form is completed and data sent back to the central database.

What will be the best way to transfer the data, the laptops will be remote and may be on a slow connection.

I will be using SQL Server 2008, Entity Framework, .Net 4

I have looked at the Microsoft Sync Framework but unsure if this will do whats required, also thought about having a web service where the windows form client can pull and push data to.

I have had bad experiences with MSMQ so what to avoid this.

How would you approach this?

Comment: Could you explain why MSMQ didn't work for you? It would be a shame to disregard it as it appears to fit the problem quite well.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [merge replication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152746.aspx) for SQL Server. This would allow your laptop users to make changes to the data they've received while offline and later sync back to the central database.

Comment: only valid for commercial version of SQL Server (not express), for anyone's future reference.

Answer (score 0):

I believe MS Sync framework is designed to handle just this problem.  While you can use MSMQ, you'd be writing most of the logic to do the syncing yourself.  Sync framework should give you a better abstraction and take care of most of the details.